# Creating a Linux (or Minecraft) Macro that would change the seed number to a random number and start the server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, linux

I am new to Linux so any help is good help. I am trying to make a Minecraft Hardcore server for me and friends, where once you die, you are dead and can only spectate, but that is not what I need help with. I want to try to find a command or macro on either Linux or minecraft itself to go in to the properties file, change the seed to a random number, and start up the server again (a nice feature would also be to turn off the server first, but I can do that if I need to) The whole idea of this is so it is like a one life server, but the map changes every time we all die. Any help would be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Nice idea, but I'm pretty sure the best way to start up a new world with a new seed is by simply creating a new world. If you change only the seed file, the generation of terrain would be affected, but anything that would already be generated from the previous session would remain. You might as well delete the whole content of the world save file.

Comment: Yeah that is a good idea, I should do that. I still want to figure out if I could do this automatically with a Linux macro or something. Anyone else have any ideas? Thank you @Quijibo!

Comment: Glad I could help! Unfortunately, I don't have the skills to answer your question, but if you don't get any answers here, try figuring out how to create such a macro yourself. If you encounter any problems, fell free to ask your coding/macro questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: It's definitely possible. You can edit the file using `sed` and delete the old world using `rm`. And Linux comes with a random string generator, so generating a new seed is pretty easy too. But unfortunately  this has not much to do with gaming.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with the world being deleted, you can just delete the world folder (using `rm)`. When you restart the server a new world will be generated.

If you do not specify a seed in `server.properties`, it is only stored in `level.dat`, meaning that it gets reset when you delete the world folder and chosen randomly the next time you start the server.